# Find the order of 10 modulo 1001

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find $\text{ord}_{1001} 10$

Let $d = \text{ord}_{1001} 10$ and we must have $d|720$, but this is still an insane range of possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Note that $10^3 =1000 \equiv -1 \pmod {1001}$. This gives us that $10^6 \equiv (-1)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {1001}$.

Comment: Now you just need to prove that $d$ such that $10^d \equiv 1 \pmod {1001}$ does not exists between $0$ and $6$.

Comment: Once you prove $10^3\equiv -1\pmod{1001}$, $10^6\equiv 1\pmod{1001}$, it's enough to prove $10^2\not\equiv 1\pmod{1001}$ to conclude that $\text{ord}_{1001}(10)=6$. Theorem: if $a^d\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, $d>0$ and for all prime divisors $q$ of $d$ we have $a^{d/q}\not\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, then $\text{ord}_n(a)=d$.